# How to categorize the equilibrium points of a recurrence formula?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics, numerical-methods, recurrence-relations

I have the following equation:

$x_{n+2} = 108 - \frac{815 - \frac{1500}{x_n}}{x_{n+1}}$

It is given that for some initial values $x_0 = x_1$ the formula leads to $x_{n+2} = x_0$.

I need to find the polynomial from which the roots are the equilibrium points for this relation. The specified equation has 3 equilibrium points.

This is my try to find the polynomial:

$r = 108 - \frac{815 - \frac{1500}{r}}{r}$

The solutions has three roots. So there are three equilibrium points in this recurrence relation.

Question:

**- How do I judge if a stationary point is a centre, spiral, saddle or node?**

Comment: Did you ever find an initial pair that does not lead in the first 10 iterations to the fixed point $x_*=100$? How would you define a saddle point in discrete dynamics like this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the numbers and form of the expression, one might be lead to consider $y_n=1-\frac{100}{x_n}$. This parametrization also maps the fixed point $x_*=100$ to $y_*=0$. Then
$$
x_{n+2}=100+8y_{n+1}+\frac{15y_n}{x_{n+1}}\\
y_{n+2}=1-\frac{100}{100+8y_{n+1}+\frac{15y_n(1-y_{n+1})}{100}}
=\frac{8y_{n+1}+\frac{3y_n(1-y_{n+1})}{20}}{100+8y_{n+1}+\frac{3y_n(1-y_{n+1})}{20}}
$$
So when the $y_n$ are close to zero, this becomes close to the linear recursion
$$
y_{n+2}=\frac{8y_{n+1}}{100}+\frac{3y_n}{2000}
$$
The characteristic roots of this recursion are $(0.09567764, -0.01567764)$, both much smaller than $1$ in absolute value.

Any 2-cycle has the system of equations
$$
a=108-\frac{815-\frac{1500}{a}}{b}\iff a^2b=108ab-815a+1500\\
b=108-\frac{815-\frac{1500}{b}}{a}\iff ab^2=108ab-815b+1500\\
$$
so that in difference $0=(a-b)(ab+815)$. For the non-trivial solutions insertion of $ab=-815$ gives
$$
-815a=-108\cdot 815-815a+1500
$$
which is impossible, so no 2-cycles exist.

Answer (score 1):

For $$x_{n+2} = 108 - \frac{815 - \frac{1500}{x_n}}{x_{n+1}}$$ if the limit exists it is given by
$$r = 108 - \frac{815 - \frac{1500}{r}}{r}$$

Comment: How do I judge if a stationary point is a centre, spiral, saddle or node?

Comment: I really need some help. Could somebody please give me feedback?